# Can a server open two TCP sockets in c?

Tags: c, server

I have a server that listens for incoming connections and processes the data from a client. Then, on the same server, I want to open another TCP sockets that send the data to another server without using the set socket() option.

this a code example:

```
int main()
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    char server_message[50] = "Message recivied";
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    int status_connect= connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) 
    &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    if (status_connect < 0) {
        printf("Error connecting to the socket \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    listen(sockfd, 10);
    int client_socket;
    client_socket = accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL);
    send(client_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0);
    do {
    char clinet_message[256];
    recv(net_socket, &clinet_message, sizeof(server_resp), 0 );
    sending_client_message(&clinet_message);

    }while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no specific limit on the number of connected sockets or listening sockets that a machine may have at a given time.  It is routine for there to be several.  It is unclear to me, however, what you mean by "without using the set socket() option."  If you want to initiate a connection to another machine, then you must first create a socket and then connect it, and for that to succeed, the machine to which you are trying to connect must also be listening for such connections.

Comment: So, did you try doing it and have a problem? If not, it seems like there's an easy thing to check before asking a question. If you did try it, then you should have some specific code and a specific problem to ask about. In general you can open multiple sockets.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I created a socket that receives messages from clients. Then, on another function, I want to create another socket that sends the received data to another server for further process. If there's a socket that binds and listening for an incoming connection. can it be possible to open a second socket while the first one listening?

Comment: Yes.  Proxy servers exist.

Comment: @Mubarark - What do you actually mean when you say: "_can it be possible to open a second socket while the first one listening_?"? By _listening_, do you mean the time between `listen()` and `accept()`? As the other commenters suggested, of course you can, but just as well you can open the other socket before _listening_ (provided the other server is already up).

Comment: What do you mean with "the set socket() option"? Do you mean `setsockopt()`, or `socket()` (the two system calls), or something else, what?

Comment: And yes, of course you can open two sockets. Just do the system calls. The bigger problem is juggling the data between them and not blocking on one while you should read the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a server that listens for incoming connections and processes
> the data from a client. Then, on the same server, I want to open
> another TCP sockets that send the data to another server without using
> the set socket() option.

There is no specific limit on the number of unconnected, connected, and listening sockets that a system or an individual process may have open at any given time.  It is routine for a system to have many, and not uncommon for individual processes to have more than one.

But you need to understand that each socket is represented by a specific file descriptor number (or even by more than one).  The same file descriptor cannot refer to two different sockets at the same time.  Furthermore, the same socket cannot be both connected and listening.

The `socket()` function is used to create a socket.  From there, for a TCP socket, your options are to either

- `connect()` it to a peer, OR
- use it to `listen()` for and `accept()` connections from peers.

You cannot use the same socket for both.  Instead, create separate sockets via `socket()` for listening and for initiating connections.  Create multiple of each if you want to listen on multiple ports or connect to multiple peers.

Comment: when the server tries to open the second socket, the program errors out with too many file descriptors.

Comment: @Mubarark, you must make sure to `close()` each file descriptor after you are done with it, because there is, indeed, a limit on how many open files any one user may have at once.  But it's normally much larger than the six needed to support a program that does only what the one presented is trying to do.  In any case, that's tangential to both the question and this answer.

Comment: Clarification: there is no *specific* limit on open sockets, but there is a limit on open files, towards which sockets count, whose value is *context dependent*.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use a single socket for multiple connections. Not in Linux at least but it should not be possible in other OS'es as well. A file descriptor given out by socket() can not be associated with more than one connection. If you try to connect() to an already connected socket you just get EISCONN error. You need to either disconnect from the first server before connecting to another one or to get a socket() fd for every one of the TCP connections you want to have running simultaneously.

Comment: Q: "I want to open another TCP [socket]" -- A: "You can't use a single socket for..." --  yeah, I have a hard time seeing how that answers the question

Comment: As far as I get it the guy wanted to receive incoming connections and to connect to some other server using a single file descriptor. I just indicated that there is no way around calling socket() twice.

Comment: but the server errors with too many files open.